# How do responsive images work with `em` supplied as a length in `sizes`?

Tags: html, image, responsive-design, font-size, srcset

How can browsers understand the `em` unit when used in a responsive image?

```
<img alt="A giraffe" src="giraffe.jpg"
     srcset="giraffe@1.5x.jpg 600w, giraffe@2x.jpg 800w, [etc.]"
     sizes="(max-width: 40em) 40em">
```

This validates, and I'm not seeing warnings in browser consoles. But if the whole point of the image preloader is to fetch images *before* the CSS is downloaded and parsed, what does the browser use for `em`?

Is it just its default `font-size` that it applies to `<html>`? Should I use `rem` for clarity? Is there a difference between the two when the user zooms?

This isn't theoretical; I'm [using `em` in my media query breakpoints](http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/), and some images are constrained by a container sized for optimal line length ([using `em`](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/em/), of course).

I checked the spec, but it's remarkably terse on the new responsive image features.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bent the ears of the guys inside the official W3C #respimg chatroom, and [this is what they had to say](http://ircbot.responsiveimages.org/bot/log/respimg/2015-06-04#T132199):

> <Tigt>  Pardon me folks, I had a question about how `em` is interpreted when used inside `sizes`
>   <TabAtkins>  Tigt: Same as in Media Queries - they're relative to the initial font size.
>   <TabAtkins>  (Not the font size on <html>, the *initial* font size, as set by the user's personal settings.)
>
> ---
>
> <Wilto> 16px almost everywhere, so long as you haven’t changed the `font-size` of `html`.
>   <TabAtkins>  Tigt: rem is treated identical to em here.

So the speed-read is:

- When used in `sizes` or media queries, `em` and `rem` are both specced to mean "the user's default `font-size`.
- The actual `em` or `rem` that controls how the image is laid out on the page can end up different if your CSS changes it
- This means one should *not* change the default size of `em` if they want to give the image preloader truthful information

[W3C Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

> This media query expresses that style sheet is usable on screen and handheld devices if the width of the viewport is greater than 20em.
>
> ```
>  @media handheld and (min-width: 20em), screen and (min-width: 20em) { … }
> ```
>
> The ‘em’ value is relative to the initial value of ‘font-size’.

Comment: @humble.rumble: Well it seems you haven't understood the specific question. And the default fontsize on Mac and Windows for Safari/Chrome/Firefox and even IE is 16px if you don't change it in your configuration.

Comment: that's rough for me as I'm setting the `font-size` of the `html` at larger window sizes in order to scale everything up :(

Comment: What do you mean by "one should not change the default size of `em`"? Do you mean in the browser's preferences, or by setting `html { font-size: ... }`?

Comment: @Flimm Something like `html { font-size: 16px }`, yes (since [browsers do change their default to something other than 16](https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2016/03/people-don-t-change-the-default-16px-font-size-in-their-browser.html#default-font-size-in-browsers-is-always-16px))

Answer (score -1):

> ### 5.1.1. Font-relative lengths: the ‘em’, ‘ex’, ‘ch’, ‘rem’ units
>
> Aside from ‘rem’ (which refers to the font-size of the root element), the font-relative lengths refer to the font metrics of the element on which they are used. The exception is when they occur in the value of the ‘font-size’ property itself, in which case they refer to the computed font metrics of the parent element (or the computed font metrics corresponding to the initial values of the ‘font’ property, if the element has no parent).
>
> #### em unit
>
> Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the element on which it is used.
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths

`em` css units are equal to the font size of the current element. The `font-size` property is inherited. Therefore the element (`img` in this case) will be sized according to 40 times the `font-size` property. If the user zooms the page (which increases the font size) the `em` unit's update to that of the `font-size` property automatically.

The base font size will be determined by the browser, if the browser is running on windows on mac and the user has not changed the font size then base font size will be 16px (usually). On Linux, BSD or any other system the font size will be set by the desktop environment and can vary.

So while conservatively you could assume that the font size is 16px, in a lot of cases you would be wrong.

Comment: Right, but what does the browser preloader do without the CSS to inform what `em` turns out to be?

Comment: Oh, absolutely, I understand how the image is eventually sized. But when the browser preloader has to guess at how big the image will be, given only the `sizes` attribute and none of the CSS that hasn't been processed into a render tree yet, is there a specced value for `em`?

Comment: Do you have a test case somewhere to check the computed value with different browsers and root font size settings?